# qt5 force children to emit a signal

Tags: qt, signals

I have a Widget that contains a bunch of `QCheckBox` in it. I'd like to have all these checkboxes emitting the `stateChanged(int)` signal. How is that implemented? I don't mind if all children of my class emit this signal (as opposed to only the `QCheckBox` instances).

Comment: I think you may do this by using `foreach(auto *p, findChildren<QCheckBox*>()) QMetaObject::invokeMethod(p, "stateChanged", Q_ARG(int,p->checkState()));` (not tried.. may contain errors or crash on full moon).

Comment: Thanks @Johaness Schaub - litb, will try this.